# Moving non-writeable files vs moving non-writeable directories

Tags: files, permissions, directory

I'm a bit puzzled about the following behavior (Linux, Debian 8.3, ext2 filesystem)

```
test@linux:~$ ls -ld directory/ file
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 10 18:51 directory/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Mar 10 18:51 file
test@linux:~$ ls -ld target_directory/
drwxr-xr-x 2 test test 4096 Mar 10 18:47 target_directory/
test@linux:~$ mv file target_directory/
test@linux:~$ mv directory/ target_directory/
mv: cannot move ‘directory/’ to ‘target_directory/directory’: Permission denied
```

And that's even the case if `directory/` is empty. Funny: `rmdir directory/` works in that case. 
 Why? It would be nice to know why `mv` behaves so differently for a file and a directory, that both don't have write permissions.

---

Actually in the vein of "give a man a fish...", don't hesitate to point me to a book which explains this and the permissions system ***correctly*** because (mini-rant) I constantly see stuff like that (from a well-known Linux book):

> ```
> $ ls -ld ch3 test
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 joe sales 4983 Jan 18 22:13 ch3
> drwxr-xr-x 2 joe sales 1024 Jan 24 13:47 test
> ```
>
> The first line shows that the `ch3` file has read and write permission for the owner and the group. All other users have read permission, which means they can view the file but cannot change its contents or remove it.

**PS/Warning: Yes, the description in the passage above is factually wrong. Don't tell me that or "correct" the post. I just quoted it here to illustrate how much half-knowledge about this issue is floating around.**

Comment: I suggest that you review how permissions work with directories as they act quite different than files.

Comment: @mdpc: 'reviewing' ... I'm still learning. Any suggestion where I can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Removing a directory *or* a file has only to do with permissions on the directory which *contains* the file/dir to be removed.  Permissions on the file/dir itself are irrelevant.  Hence why you can remove `directory` using `rmdir` even though it's owned by `root`: you didn't show it in your output, but you clearly have read, write and execute permissions on the directory which *contains* `directory`.

I've written more elsewhere on [what exactly each individual permission on a directory lets you accomplish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251302/135943).

As for why you can't move `directory` into `target_directory`, I'm not sure.  I'm unable to reproduce this on my box.  There are a host of reasons that could be causing this, ranging from extended attributes being set on `directory`, to the possibility that `target_directory` could be a mount point for a separate filesystem than that which contains `directory`.  **Permissions alone aren't the reason, however.**

(P.S.: Next time pick better example names; using the names "directory" and "file" make it really annoying to try to describe what's happening.)

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because moving the `directory` into `target directory` changes the `..` entry inside `directory` and since you're not allowed to write in `directory`, it is not permitted?

I experienced the same (and was puzzled similarly as OP) with a directory that was mine, but the owner-write permission wasn't set. Simply setting `chmod u+w` on the directory made me allow the move (on the same partition, no copying and deleting). After reading this thread, it made me realize the above situation. It fully explains why with files there is no such problem.